# MAUI app throws error before emulator running after target upgrade to .NET8

Tags: c#, android, maui, visual-studio-2022

I have a rather simple .NET MAUI app which I'm developing in Visual Studio on Win10 and then test it by running it in an emulator. It worked fine until I upgraded the target framwork to from .NET7 to .NET8.

Now it shows this error before the startup:

> "The debug target `Pixel 5 - API 34 (Android 14.0 - API 34)` is not
> compatible with the active target framework `iOS`, please select a
> valid debug target for `iOS`."

I understand it's trying to load the iOS build in my Android emulator for some reason but I don't know how to fix this. I went through the options in the project properties and saw the possibility to completely disable iOS building but I don't want that - I want my app to work on both Android and iOS.

What am I doing wrong here?

The `csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-ios;net8.0-android33.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <RootNamespace>MyAPp</RootNamespace>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>MyAPp</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.ppg.MyAPp</ApplicationId>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>
        
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0-ios'">14.2</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0-android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <UseInterpreter Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios')) AND '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">True</UseInterpreter>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView" Version="23.1.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Maui.Core" Version="23.1.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Maui.DataGrid" Version="23.1.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Maui.Controls" Version="23.1.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Maui.Editors" Version="23.1.6" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\MyAPp.API.Models\MyAPp.API.Models.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\MyAPp.Entities\MyAPp.Entities.csproj" />
        <TrimmableAssembly Include="DevExpress.Data.v23.1" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Folder Include="Interfaces\" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Update="Views\SettingsPage.xaml.cs">
        <DependentUpon>SettingsPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
      </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <MauiXaml Update="Views\ArticleDetailPage.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Views\ArticleListPage.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Views\DocDetailPage.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Views\DocItemPage.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Views\SettingsPage.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Views\StoreDocsPage.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
    </ItemGroup>    
</Project>
```

Comment: Can you show us how your project file looks like?

Comment: Added the csproj file

Comment: I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Did you solve the issue? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are using incorrect TargetFramework

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>net8.0-ios;net8.0-android33.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

Should look like this:

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>net8.0-ios;net8.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
```

Also change this as well

```
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-ios'">14.2</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
```